# A Group of Order 6

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that G is a group of order 6 and that $a,b \in G,$ where $a \neq b.$ If both $a$ and $b$ have order 2, justify that G is generated by $a$ and $b$.

By the order requirement, $a^2=e$, and $b^2=e$ and 2 is the smallest number for which this is the case. Namely, $a \neq e,$ and $b \neq e.$ So far, our group consists of $G=\{e,a,b \}.$ It must be closed under multiplication, so $ab \in G$. Also, a quick computation shows that $(ab)^{-1}=ba,$ so $ba \in G.$ However, I need one more element, and I need to prove that all of these are distinct and exhaust the possibilities and I have no idea how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: No group has exactly two elements of order $2$. (Why?)

Comment: any group of order 6 is cyclic (so doesn’t have two elements of order $2$) or isomorphic to $S_3$

Answer (score 4):

The subgroup $\langle a, b \rangle$ has order $>3$ since $\langle a \rangle$ is a proper subgroup of $\langle a, b \rangle$. By Lagrange's theorem, the order of $\langle a, b \rangle$ can only be $6$.

Comment: Btw, the missing element is $aba$ ($=bab$)

Comment: Hm? What do you mean?

Comment: Why must aba=bab?